# Deleting elements from a list if they do not follow 'if' 'or' statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to get rid of unwanted variables in a list. I need to have two condition: one is if making sure the values in my array are smaller than a variable A, and the other is making sure they are not equal to another variable B.

This code dose not work:

```
original_Ar = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
new_Ar = [s for s in original_Ar if (s != 2) or (s < 10)]

print (new_Ar)
```

while if I split it into two statements (instead of the `or` statement) - they do work:

```
original_Ar = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
print ([s for s in original_Ar if (s != 2)])
print ([s for s in original_Ar if (s < 10)])
```

Any idea how can I do that in one line?

Comment: try using `and` instead of `or`

Comment: Out of interest why did you use `or`, since you used "and" when you wrote the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have your boolean logic mixed up. You want to include all values that are not equal to 2 **and** are smaller than 10:

```
new_Ar = [s for s in original_Ar if s != 2 and s < 10]
#           *both* conditions must be true ^^^
```

Otherwise, you'd include `s = 2`, because it is smaller than ten, and you'd include `s = 11` and `s = 12`, because both are not equal to two!