# Get a list of objects with the maximum attribute value in a list of objects

Tags: python, list, attributes, max

Slightly different from [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984283/deleting-elements-from-a-list-if-they-do-not-follow-if-or-statements). I have found here:
`front_Ar` is a list of objects with a `score` attribute.

I am trying to get a list of all objects with the highest score.
I have tried:

```
maxind = []
maxInd.append(max(front_Ar, key=attrgetter('score')))
```

which stored only one object (presumably the first one it found).
Any idea how can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the max score first, then filter the list based on that score:

```
max_score = max(front_Ar, key=attrgetter('score')).score
max_ind = [obj for obj in front_Ar if obj.score == max_score]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `max()` function can be used to find the *value* of the highest score.

To get the objects whose score matches that value, you could do a list comprehension like in @juanpa.arrivillaga's answer, or use something like `filter()` on the list to return only the items matching your criterion.

```
top_score = max(front_Ar, key=attrgetter('score')).score
max_ind = list(filter(lambda x: x.score == top_score, front_Ar))
```